# How can I see where tests are failing?

Tags: unit-test, ant

I have a unmanaged package that I am codeveloping with a colleague; we are using the Force.com ANT migration tool to deploy and retrieve the package contents into our own developer orgs.For some reason, our unit tests are running fine in our separate orgs.

[image: Working Tests]

However when we deploy code using the migration tool (`$ant deploy code`) the test's fail and have 0% code coverage.

Luckily we are using Git to manage our source code, however the problem has only just begun today and I have created a new branch and reverted all changes and the problem is still occurring.

Where can I see why the tests are failing? All tests are executing fine in our different orgs, but when using ant they fail.

[image: Deployment Screenshot]

Comment: What is the output from Ant? Can you post your target from build.xml?

Comment: Are you using `@isTest(seeAllData=true)`? What is the testLevel in your ANT build file? I assume your package contains tests; are you deploying the tests as well?

Comment: @DanielHoechst the ANT output just displays the code coverage failures.

Comment: @DerekF not using seeAllData, as thats just completely wrong. Yes there are test files.

Comment: It would be very helpful to post your build.xml.